# how to search multiple username in a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I want to search for some username in my database like this->

```
$skip = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['skip_user'] = array();
array_push($_SESSION['skip_user'],$skip);
$str = $_SESSION['skip_user'];
$string = rtrim(implode(',', $str), ',');
```

Now string variable looks like "name1, name2, name3";

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username in ({$string}) ORDER BY id DESC");
```

This fetches the users but i don't want these users. I mean is there any query where i can i write `WHERE username !in ({$string})`!

get all users except "name1, name2, name3" these users

Now after adding NOT IN I'm receiving error

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE username NOT IN ({$string}) ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysqli_error($db)); php is giving error Unknown column 'name1' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: You are looking for the `WHERE NOT IN ()``functionality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `NOT IN` in the SQL query.

First though try to add quotes to the values you are trying in the `NOT IN` part of the sql query.

```
$str = '';
foreach ($_SESSION['skip_user'] AS $word) {
    $str .= "'$word',";
}
$str = rtrim($str, ',');
```

Then use this `$str` in your query. Also, try to make a habit out of using `` for column names, like this:

```
SELECT `SOMETHING` FROM `TABLE_NAME` WHERE <CONDITION>
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: I'm receiving an error in the query. mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users  WHERE username NOT IN ({$string}) ORDER BY id DESC")or die(mysqli_error($db)); php is giving error Unknown column 'name1' in 'where clause'

Comment: @SagarSingh - becauseof the quotes missing, read my answer for the solution.

Comment: you can still use implode no reason to loop

Comment: @Pamblam can i use AND query also with it? like this-> `WHERE username NOT IN ({$string}) AND id NOT IN ({$id})`

Comment: Yes, this is also valid SQL, as long as `{$id}` contains correctly formatted string!

Comment: just like you did.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `NOT IN` to exclude certain values.

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username NOT IN ('name1', 'name2') ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 1):

yep, just type "not" instead of "!"

select * from table where junk not in ('item1', 'item2', 'item3');

1) You have a few other problems though you're not adding quotes to your implode:

```
// you need quotes here
$string = implode("','", $str);
// And here
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username in ('{$string}') ORDER BY id DESC");
```

However, this is what you should **really** be doing.

2) You should bind your parameters instead as you're open to SQL injection:

```
$params = array();
$params[0] = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username NOT IN (";
foreach($str as $s){
    $params[0] .= "s";
    array_push($params, $s);
    $sql .= "?, ";
}
$sql = rtrim($sql, " ,").") ORDER BY id DESC";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

// this is the same as doing: $stmt->bind_param('s', $param);
call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $params);

// execute and get results
$stmt->execute();
```